# How do I add white space between word

Tags: php

I want to add space to word something like this

```
CountryName
RegionName
ZipPostalCode
```

to be

```
Country Name
Region Name
Zip Postal Code
```

Let me know how can be done with php

Comment: By what rule exactly? Can you ignore cases like `McDonalds` where the case change is part of the name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to find [lowercase character][uppercase character] and insert a space:

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/s','$1 $2', $oldstr);
```

Comment: It worked for camelCase but not for all lower case words.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $old);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [CakePHP's Inflector class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0/cake/libs/inflector.php) for guidance (for example the humanize function).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$str = 'HelloThere';
$str= preg_replace('/(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])/'," $1", $str);
echo trim($str); //Hello There
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they all camelCase like that? You can turn it into an array, then turn that into a string.

```
<?php
function splitCamelCase($str) {
  return preg_split('/(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])/', $str);
}

print_r(splitCamelCase("ZipPostalCode"));
?>
```

Edit: Disregard this - Mark's answer is better.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
//  It can be done as:
echo 'Country ','Name <br>';
echo 'Region ','Name <br>';
echo 'Zip ','Postal ','Code';

//   OR

echo 'Country ','Name <br> Region ','Name <br> Zip ','Postal ','Code';

?>
```